# Edit method return value in a debugger

Tags: java, debugging

Given the following Java code, how can I use the IntelliJ or Eclipse debugger to return `false` from the condition() method?

```
public boolean condition() {
    return (4 == add());
}

public int add() {
    return 2 + 2;
}
```

Answer (score 16, accepted):

In Eclipse you can use [Force Return](http://help.eclipse.org/mars/index.jsp?topic=%2Forg.eclipse.jdt.doc.user%2Freference%2Fviews%2Fshared%2Fref-forcereturn.htm).

Just place a breakpoint on `return (4 == add());` and type `false` on the Display view-tab. Then make a selection of your `false`, right click and hit "Force Return".

Comment: Thanks, it works for me, I have a method which return an null object and when forcing the return by instantiating a new instance in the Display view it works.

Comment: Is there any way to do this automatically, I hate keeping track of 6 - 19 different variables I have to set during dbugging

Comment: cann anybody explain what is the "Display view-tab" ?

Answer (score 7):

In IntelliJ (since IDEA 15 EAP) you can use [Force return](https://blog.jetbrains.com/idea/2015/09/intellij-idea-15-eap-improves-debugger-and-git-support/).

**Extract from jetbrains' blog**

You can force the return from the current method without executing any more instructions from it:

[image]

NB :

If the method returns a value, you’ll have to specify it (smart code completion provided).

If the method has try-finally blocks, you’ll be able to choose whether to execute them or not.

Comment: Looks promising, but in my Android Studio, when specifying the return value in the dialog, the confirm button doesn't work, and then cancelling the dialog gets me into some weird unexpected state. :/

Answer (score -2):

You can first change the code for `condition` to something like this:

```
public boolean condition() {
   boolean result = (4 == add());
   return result;
}
```

Then, you can set a breakpoint on the `return` statement. When the breakpoint is hit, you can use the debugger to change the value of `result` to `false`.

Comment: I agree that works, but that is an answer to a different question.

Comment: I'm specifically asking how change the return value on the call stack at runtime. You've suggested that I create a new variable at compile time, then edit that call stack variable at runtime.

Comment: You can only use the IDE debugger can only change the value of a variable. Changing the code (as in my answer) is the only way to do what you want.

Comment: @cybersam: Wrong, see the other answer :-).