# Eclipse Debugger: How to Force Return (cannot find Display)

Tags: eclipse, debugging

There are guides how to Force Return from the Debugger (Sources: [1](https://stackoverflow.com/a/35703711/6665108), [2](https://liuzy163.wordpress.com/2015/01/13/eclipse-force-return-at-debug-time/)), which always state to open the Display View to enter the new return value. However using Eclipse 2021-12 I cannot find the Display View. In Source 1 the last comment shows that the Display View might be missing at least since 11/2020.

How can one Force Return with the current Eclipse version? Where to insert the chosen return value, instead of the Display View?

Comment: It is called "Debug Shell" these days

Comment: Still I cannot get the Force Return to work. Typing "null" or "return null;" into the Debug Shell, executing it, right-clicking the return statement of the function and selecting "Force Return", nothing works.

Comment: When the breakpoint was reached I just typed `null` in the Debug View, selected it, and then righted click "Force Return". This worked fine for me.

Comment: Seems like it is not intuitive, trying to do the same thing you did was not working in most cases. I needed to select the value in the Debug Shell and press Alt+Shift+F. Right-clicking anywhere in code (or selecting any code) and using the context menu button resulted in an error.